# How can I know whether the memory is invalid before the system crash?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

It is known an access to the invalid memory leads a segment fault, which can make the system crash. I hope to know whether the memory is invalid before the system crash.

Comment: null check is about the only thing you can really do.

Comment: Maybe the memory is not null but invalid.

Answer (score 2):

This is Linux-specific, but simple and reliable to implement.

Open `/proc/self/maps`. It is a text pseudo-file, which lists all the memory maps for the current process. It is described in [man 5 proc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html); see the `/proc/[pid]/maps` section. The lines look something like

```
7fb5cb179000-7fb5cb32e000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 14651     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
```

but you only need to parse the starting address in hexadecimal up to the dash `-`, the ending address (not inclusive; it is the first address just outside the map) in hexadecimal up to the space , and some mode letters up to the next space .

Mode letter `r` means the mapping is readable, `w` writable, `x` executable, `s` shared, and `p` private. (There might perhaps be other letters in the future, so it is best to ignore everything except those and a space .)

Because `long` is the largest standard integer type in C, you should use `unsigned long` for the addresses (including when parsing them). You can also convert any pointer to an address using `(unsigned long)pointer`. Using `int` just won't work on most 64-bit Linux architectures, at it tends to be 32-bit, and thus unable to represent all pointers.

If the pointer address is outside all of those maps, it is guaranteed to be invalid: dereferencing the pointer will give you a segmentation fault.

If the pointer is within one of the above maps, the mode of the map describes which operations are valid, and what kind of map it is. If you know the pointer is intended to point to data, you know the target map should not be executable, for example.

In a multithreaded program, you will want to try to read the entire file into memory at once, so that you'll see a consistent snapshot of the memory maps, and then parse the data using string operations. If you find you did not read a full file, simply re-read the file. You should use low-level I/O  from `unistd.h` (instead of using functions from `stdio.h` or `mman.h`) to do this, to avoid any caching and abstractions. In fact, I recommend this procedure for single-threaded applications, too; it is a robust approach.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that there is no portable, reliable way of doing this.

Which is 100% correct and as it should be. What you are asking is "How can I make my program detect that I have a bug in my program?" - the only way you can get an invalid pointer is if you have a bug (or just plain badly written code).

The idea of using valgrind or similar to analyze the code and fix any bugs that cause bad memory access is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting topic. Please take a look at discussion here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/49550/

Microsoft provided a function for this purpose: IsBadReadPtr ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366781(VS.85).aspx )

I could not find anything like that for Linux. However, you can run your program in valgrind ( http://valgrind.org/ ) to detect invalid pointer references.

Comment: [`IsBad*Ptr()` is a bad thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

On modern multiuser operating systems, invalid memory access won't crash the system - it will only crash your program that made the invalid access.